# Prevent drag drop shadow changing when base view changes

Tags: xamarin.forms, drag-and-drop

I am trying to create a tile based game board games in Xamarin forms.

This requires dragging tiles onto the board from their hand (think Scrabble...)

I have a nice drag-drop system going:

```
class Tile : Frame
{

    public Tile(int row, int col, String letter, bool planted)
    {
        this.Planted = planted;
        this.Row = row;
        this.Col = col;

        this.BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow;
        this.BorderColor = Color.Blue;
        this.Padding = 2;

        label = new Label {
            TextColor = Color.Black,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Blue,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
        };

        drag = new DragGestureRecognizer { };
        drag.DragStarting += OnDragStarting;
        drag.DropCompleted += OnDropCompleted;

        drop = new DropGestureRecognizer { };
        drop.DragOver += OnDragOver;
        drop.DragLeave += OnDragLeave;
        drop.Drop += OnDrop;
    }
...
}
```

However as soon as I start the drag, I need to "blank out" this tile in the player's hand. The problem is that when I do this, the shadow of the drag also gets blanked out. What I need to do is somehow take a snapshot of the view, and use that as the shadow, before making changes to the underlying view, but I can't see any way of doing so...

```
    void OnDragStarting(object sender, DragStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Data.Properties.Add("Tile", this);
        this.label.Text = "";
        //this will affect both the original view, and the shadow
        //I want the shadow to keep the same view state as before
        //the drag started
        this.label.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray;            
    }
```

Comment: Can you "clone" the tile, and drag the clone? This would allow you to change the original. OR an alternative solution: Have an invisible BoxView layered on top of the tile. With BackgroundColor matching what is underneath the tile. To "blank out" the tile, set IsVIsible="True" on that BoxView. [This problem isn't specific to Xamarin Forms; AFAIK, any drag-and-drop system would require a similar solution. If you need to change an object in one place, but not the other, then you either need two objects, or you need to "cover" one of them.] BTW, don't need xamarin.forms in title - its in the tag.

Comment: yes I'm thinking something like that is probably the way I'll have to go with this... I'll probably just place a blanker view on top of the top of the tile when the drag starts

Comment: So, is it work?

Comment: Yes, it seems to